# Grab n-th frame from video for preview

Tags: javascript

If I have a video file in a javascript document, how do I grab a frame from the middle?  This grabs the current frame, but I want a frame from the middle for a thumbnail.  Is this something that can be easily done?  This kind of works, but I'm not able to set the frame back to the beginning after the grab is finished.

http://jsbin.com/betibe

```
var v = document.getElementById('v');
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

draw(v,context,cw,ch);
v.currentTime = 5;

function draw(v,c,w,h) {
  c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
  setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
}
```

Comment: It can be done, but not with javascript, it needs to be done on the server using a video encoding tool such as ffmpeg

Comment: @andrew can you post an answer elaborating on why it isn't possible?

Comment: @JanDvorak turns out i was mistaken, posted an example of how it can be done using a canvas

Comment: it's not working for me, what do I need to update to grab the nth frame?

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for the previous answer,

```
video.seekTo({ frame: frameNum });
```

did the trick for me. Customize the frameNum however you want.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6Zq/304/)

HTML:

```
  <div class="frame">  
  <span id="currentFrame">0</span>
  </div>

<video height="180" width="100%" id="video"> 
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
</video>

<div id="controls">
  <button id="play-pause">Play</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var currentFrame = $('#currentFrame');
var frameNum =100;

var video = VideoFrame({
    id : 'video',
    frameRate: 29.97,
    callback : function(frame) {
        currentFrame.html(frame);
    }
});

video.seekTo({ frame: frameNum });


$('#play-pause').click(function(){
    if(video.video.paused){
        video.video.play();
        video.listen('frame');
        $(this).html('Pause');
    }else{
        video.video.pause();
        video.stopListen();
        $(this).html('Play');
    }
});
```

For reference on the videoframe visit: https://github.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame

Comment: I'm not seeing how this works.  It seems like no matter what I put it still shows the 0th frame.

Comment: Please post the code here. Jsfiddle can die at any moment or be blocked for somebody. I can't fit it on my phone screen, for example

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a canvas

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jhph2ay0/)**

**Example** taken from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/64256/)

Javascript

```
  window.onload = function() {

    var video = document.getElementById('my_video');
    var thecanvas = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
    var img = document.getElementById('thumbnail_img');


    video.addEventListener('pause', function() {

      draw(video, thecanvas, img);

    }, false);

  };


  function draw(video, thecanvas, img) {

    // get the canvas context for drawing
    var context = thecanvas.getContext('2d');

    // draw the video contents into the canvas x, y, width, height
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, thecanvas.width, thecanvas.height);

    // get the image data from the canvas object
    var dataURL = thecanvas.toDataURL();

    // set the source of the img tag
    img.setAttribute('src', dataURL);

  }
```

HTML

```
  The Video
  <br />
  <video id="my_video" controls>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <br /> The Canvas
  <br />
  <canvas id="thecanvas">
  </canvas>
  <br /> The Image
  <br />
  <img id="thumbnail_img" alt="Right click to save" />
  <br />
```

Comment: How do you get the nth frame from load?